# How to automatically go to the last edited position on file open in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

When you open a document, there is a bookmark icon beside the scroll bar, asking if you want to go to the last position. This is the behavior I want, I just want it to execute automatically every time files are opened. In other words, when there are multiple documents opened, opening any document should jump to the last edited position of that document.

Application.GoBack in AutoOpen doesn't seem to work, it will go to my other documents.

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1690818/how-to-automatically-go-to-the-last-edited-position-on-file-open-in-word`) again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill It was the suggestion from the website to tell me to ask a new question. I have deleted the old one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need VBA for that:

After opening the Word document, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

The cursor should then be positioned at the last editing place.

---

For an alternative to `Application.GoBack`:

Word works by storing a built-in bookmark called `\PrevSel1`
in the document, which it can then return to.
Instead of using the Shift+F5 shortcut, you can just go to it:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\PrevSel1"
```

Comment: I know this. I don't want to press any keyboard or mouse button. I want word to do it automatically.

Comment: Try the addition to my answer. I hope it wasn't you that downvoted my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I am looking for. But word tells me, "this bookmark does not exist." Even after I have opened the document, edit it and run this macro, it still tells me that. I am not sure what is happening. It should work. I run this command in AutoOpen() by the way.

Comment: When opening the document without VBA, does go to the bookmark `\PrevSel1` work? This was how I tested it (without VBA and not in AutoOpen).

Comment: I write code like this, ```Sub AutoOpen_bak()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\PrevSel1"
End Sub```

And run it after I opened a new document. It says "Run time error 5101， this bookmark does not exist."

Comment: If I use the "bookmark" command in the toolbar, the "go to" command is greyed with "\PrevSel1".